# forced break usage

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Let's say I need to go on a trip, and thus will be skipping some of my gym sessions.

Can I say

```
I'm taking a *forced break* from gym
```

or another phrase should be used here?

Comment: If you "need" to go, as you say, and so miss gym sessions, you might say a "necessary break". Alternatively, if you must miss the sessions, you could say a "mandatory break". If somebody or something is forcing you to miss the sessions, your "forced break" works.

Comment: @JEL I mean in case I don't want but have to

Comment: You could use "unwanted but necessary", but if by "have to" you mean somebody or something is forcing you to miss the sessions, your "forced break" is more concise and seems to me to cover the same territory as "unwanted but necessary".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could, but I think that "forced" is a little strong. **Unavoidable** seems better.

I think *forced break from gym* implies a direct connection between the gym and the break, that there is something specific to the gym or to your activity there that is forcing the break, such as an injury or the building being refurbished.

After all, a forced absence from work is not a period when you are unable to work because you are absent, but when work (i.e. your employer) forces you to absent your self.